# Visual Studio Blend Design on intel HD4400 not working

Tags: wpf, silverlight, visual-studio-2013, intel, blend

It seems there's an issue with intel integrated GPUs and Blend, resulting in degin not rendering in realtime.

I saw several solutions, updating the driver (for hd5000), or using discrete GPU when one's available.

But I'm on an hybride ultrabook (Dell XPS12), with latest intel hd4400 driver and no discrete GPU, and I have no clue how to work around this issue.

Comment: Can you provide more info? What's not working, how to reproduce, etc? I'm using win 8.1 x64 w/ hd 4000 and everything looks fine to me.

Comment: If I change anything in xaml or directly in the rendered design, no changes are reflected : If I change the content of a TextBlock, the new  content won't be displayed until I close the file and open it again.